# Is cloudlayar a legit protection service?

Tags: cdn, protection

I recently came across a very cheap protection service similar to Cloudflare called Cloudlayar:
https://cloudlayar.com/

It's a bit weird because the prices are too good to be true, no PayPal (so refund at their mercy), and they use Cloudflare to protect their own website...

Does anyone know what this company is? does really offer a service? is it a scam?

p.s: I'm not asking for an "opinion", just trying to know if this service actually works and have customers

Thanks in advance

Comment: To evaluate the company, I'd recommend searching for "cloudlayar reviews."

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, before suggesting this, have you tried your suggestion? I'm not too lazy to use google, I already searched, but I was unable to find any "real" reviews, only those generic/auto-generated ones. If you found a real review, I would appreciate if you can share it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I don't see the reason why the question was closed, I'm not asking for recommendation, and I fail to see what part in my question asks for opinion, I have clearly stated  I'm not looking for opinion. I'm looking for someone who can say "yes I have paid and got service" or "no, once I entered my credit card, my CC was stolen and I got no service". These are facts, not opinions!

Comment: i'll re-open, but my biggest concern with this question is that it is very unlikely to get an answer.  I doubt that anybody here has experience with this random small company without many online reviews.

Comment: Thanks! I doubt too, but I thought I would try my luck...